# Combining 2 audio outputs

Tags: audio, pipewire

I have an app that is play music to the default audio device (which uses pipewire).  When I using a second play command (pw-play) the command executes but that audio is not heard.  I was hoping to merge / combine the two audio streams.

Is there a way to cause the audio to be combined?  (Instead of the first play command only being heard)

**UPDATE**:
I did have problems getting sound to play (from a service running as root).  So I created a script that runs pw-play using sudo, and that seemed to work on its own.  When I run the script (from the service) I hear audio play.  But, if I'm playing music (using shairport-sync) and then run the script it will not result in additional audio being played.

Using 'ps' I discovered that a bunch of my playback scripts are in state code S, so are suspended and waiting on something.  Even the speak-test I ran is in S state.  I tried restarting the shairport-sync service but that did not allow the other processes to continue.  I'm not sure how to diagnose this - how can I figure out what these stuck processes are waiting on?  If pipewire is supposed to merge audio then it shouldn't block the scripts...

Comment: Pulsewire most definitely does that mixing – that's why you can play music while browsing youtube in firefox while some program makes an audible notification. So, that definitely works for everyone else – it probably does for you as well!

I bet the problem here is that you're trying to run `pw-play` from a shell that's not the active seat. Can you tell us in which context you're running `pw-play`?

Comment: by the way, it's pretty rare that people actually use `pw-play`; because pipewire and pulseaudio have an ALSA emulation layer, you can just use *any* software that knows how to use ALSA, for example `ffplay`, `gst-launch`… . I consider `pw-play` to be more of a demo program, as it really can't play *any* modern audio formats.

Comment: I tried to answer the question above (context).  THe active seat comment is interesting...it sounds like the problem I've been trying to work around.  If there is a better way to allow the service to play sounds let me know.  (The 'sudo pw-play' felt like a hack)

Comment: Pipewire and other audio systems have a notion of active seats, i.e. multiple users can be logged in at the same time, but at most one user is sitting in front of a screen with headphones or speakers. What you're trying to do is to send audio although the user sending that audio is not actively owning the seat. That's why the attempt blocks when you're already using audio. That is kind of intended! Pipewire does mix audio, but by default it will only mix the different audio streams of the user owning the seat.

Comment: Since this is a server designed to run headless, which user is the active seat?  (And if I run the script as that user I assume it will resolve)

Comment: `loginctl` can tell you. I suspect you have an ssh login or something similar!

Comment: According to loginctl only the user 'sddm' has a "SEAT", seat0.  So I'll try running the pw-play as that user and update.

Comment: Don't. That seems backwards. Sddm is your graphical login prompt. You say this is a headless server - so uninstall sddm.

Comment: At the moment the server starts into graphics model (runlevel 5 equiv).  I wanted that for testing a particular app - though it could later run in text mode.  Is it safe to remove SDDM or will that damage the GUI ?  Even though headless with a GUI, is SDDM a problem?  Can I now run the play app as sddm user?